# How to get value of child node elements from XDocument in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to access values in an xml response to Bing Maps API. I tried doing something like `var responseXml = xdoc.Root.Element("Response").Element("ResourceSets").Element("ResourceSet").Element("EstimatedTotal").Value;`, but it resulted in an error.

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

code

```
private void RequestCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);
    StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

    try
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(stream);

        var responseXml = xdoc.Root.Element("Response").Element("ResourceSets").Element("ResourceSet").Element("EstimatedTotal").Value;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex.Message);
    }
    }
```

xml response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know the exact question you're asking Virtual Earth, but you posted a picture of the xml which doesn't exactly give us a clearer picture of the xml.

however, try

```
var responseXml = xdoc.Descendants("ResourceSets");
```

That should return an enumerable of XElements containing one to many "ResourceSet" XElements. Those XElements could be queried for Lat/Long with:

```
var locations = responseXml.Descendents("GeocodePoint");

foreach (var loci in locations) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Lat: {0} Long: {1}", loci.Element("Latitude"), loci.Element("Longitude"));
    }
```

Use the debugger at that line and play with the xDoc object. It has lots of properties and methods which may be of use.

Comment: Okay this makes sense, but how could I get the value of `Latitude` and `Longitude` within `GeocodePoint`?

Comment: @jedi nerd xdoc.Descendants("GeocodePoint").Element("Latitude"), seems like you have two more GeoCodePoint so use foreach or linq

Comment: @jedinerd Each descendant of an  XML document has children, with Elements. Please take my advice and look at the xDoc object in your code within the debugger or the Immediate window. There are literally dozens of methods that may help you more than our advice on SO. I added something to the original answer.

Answer (score 2):

`xdoc.Root` is `Element("Response")`, so try this:

```
var responseXml = xdoc.Root.Element("ResourceSets").Element("ResourceSet").Element("EstimatedTotal").Value;
```

Comment: Hello!  I can't believe I missed that.  However after fixing that and giving it another try I get this error message = "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @jedinerd i don't see any errors. try to output all nodes from Root to EstimatedTotal. Maybe,  you'll find, where is null